# Spring boot maven plugin skips some classes from the jar

Tags: spring-boot-maven-plugin

I try to create jar with `mvn install` , but Spring boot maven plugin skips some classes from the jar. In particular those which can are not part of my `groupId` if it is related. How to include all the classes?

Comment: You want to block the code execution till you get an answer ?

Comment: using `async/await`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to actually wait for the result of an async execution in JavaScript.  JavaScript, whether server-side or browser-based, uses a single event loop/queue.  Async operations just involve multiple events posted on the queue.  You can use async/await (in modern JS) to write your code as if it were blocking but that's just syntactic sugar.